# Rotate webcam video on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, video, webcam

I need to rotate (90 degrees) the video feed of my laptop webcam to use it with skype/hangout.

It seems to be possible using the gstreamer infrastructure, but I don't know how.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @Daniel I personally run Mint 14. Any hint to do this in any Ubuntu version would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408187/rotate-webcam-as-well-as-screen-portrait-mode

The answer by [Lucio Anibal Criollo Rivera](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback) worked for me well.

I am bringing it here for the sake of clarity:

> 1. Install utilities:
>
>    ```
>    $ sudo apt-get update
>    $ sudo apt-get install v4l-utils
>    $ sudo apt-get install v4l2loopback-utils
>    ```
> 2. Download [v4l2loopback](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback)
> 3. Uncompress 'v4l2loopback-master' folder
> 4. Compile v4l2loopback module:
>
>    ```
>    $ make
>    ```
> 5. Install:
>
>    ```
>    $ sudo make install
>    ```
> 6. Enable device:
>
>    ```
>    $ sudo modprobe v4l2loopback exclusive_caps=1
>    ```
> 7. Check if device is enabled:
>
>    ```
>    $ v4l2-ctl --list-devices
>
>    Dummy video device (0x0000) (platform:v4l2loopback-000):
>      /dev/video1
>
>    USB2.0 UVC 2M WebCam: USB2.0 UV (usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.2):
>      /dev/video0
>    ```
> 8. Copy the webcam video stream to it via ffmpeg:
>
>    ```
>    $ ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -vf "transpose=1,format=yuv420p" -f v4l2 /dev/video1
>    ```
>
> You can see for more details about paramters:
>
> https://ffmpeg.org
>
> https://www.ostechnix.com/20-ffmpeg-commands-beginners/
>
> https://github.com/qTox/qTox/wiki/Video

Comment: I used ` ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video2 -vf "transpose=2,transpose=2,format=yuv420p" -f v4l2 /dev/video4` to FLIP the camera vertically - this allowed me to do a demonstration on paper with my webcam overhead.